# NullPointerException Occurs when trying to create a file and write data to it in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a file ,if it doesnot exist and tried to write some data to it. The same program I did in java, it was running fine.But when I try to do the same thing in Android I am getting NullPointerException at the place where I am trying to write data to file. And also, I did not find any new file in the current directory .I will share the code here:

## xmlpoc.java

```
   public class xmlPoc extends Activity {

 String s="<employee>"+
               "<details>"+
               "<pictag id="+
                "\"@drawable/icon\""  +
               "mystr"+
                "="+
              "\"Picture 1\"" +
              "myint" +
               " =" +
              "\"33\"" +
               "/>"+
                " <name>SandeepKumarSuman</name>"+
               "<designation>J2ME Programmer</designation>"+
               "<city>Gorakhpur</city>"+
                "<state>UP</state>"+
             "<name>mohan</name>"+
             "<designation>J2ME GAMEProgrammer</designation>"+
              "<city>HYD</city>"+
              "<state>AP</state>"+
              "<name>hari</name>"+
              "<designation>Fresher</designation>"+
             "<city>GNT</city>"+
              "<state>AP</state>"+
               "</details>"+
               "</employee>";
          File f;
             FileOutputStream fop;
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
       f=new File("./myfile1.txt");
           try {
                fop=new FileOutputStream(f);
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!f.exists()){
     try {    
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   System.out.println("New file myfile.txt has been created to the current directory");
    }
    try {
        fop.write(s.getBytes());

     fop.flush();
     fop.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
}

Comment: Why do you think `"./myfile1.txt"` is a valid place to save a file?

Comment: I thought the file will be created in the current Directory

Answer (score 1):

Check out the android dev guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), and if you want to write to the external storage you should add the permissions to your manifest and use "getExternalStorageDirectory()", or "getExternalFilesDir()" if you are using API 8 or higher. You can't just write everywhere, that's why you need to use androids "openFileOutput(" or just write to the external storage.

External storage permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I have written file to External storage and now the file is in data/data/com.andr.filedemo/file/adbc.xml. Now I want this file to be retrieved and copied to my res folder as I need to parse this file .Is there any way to copy file from data/data/com.andr.filedemo/file/abc.xml to my res folder programatically rather than using adb pull. Plz help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: You should parse it where it was created.  The res folder does not exist in an ordinary filesystem, but is contained in the .apk (which is a read-only zip file) and so is not writeable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try `f=new File("myfile1.txt");`

Comment: no,it was still giving nullpointerException. Hey, may I know is there any API difference in Android compared to java when handling files